# Is there a keyboard shortcut for the ellipsis buttons of the Project Options in the Delphi IDE

Tags: delphi, keyboard-shortcuts, ellipsis

The Project Options in the Delphi IDE has a few option (like the `Search Path`) each with an ellipsis button (the one on the right having only three dots `...` in the [image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e28pf5xa45xtzie/Screenshot%202016-06-22%2016.25.37.png?dl=0) below) to pop-up a dialog.

What keyboard shortcut activates that button?

[image: Project Options with ellipsis button]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since the Delphi 8, ellipsis button can be activated by pressing <kbd>Alt + Down</kbd>, same as for combobox-style fields (with arrow button). Alternatively, you can press <kbd>Ctrl+Enter</kbd>.

In Delphi 7 and older, ellipsis buttons were standalone buttons so you could use <kbd>Tab</kbd> followed by the <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: Since basically forever: Delphi 2007 has it, that's the oldest version I've got on this computer, but I'd guess it dates back to at least Delphi 8.

Comment: Thanks. I think it's even in the `CUA` list `Alt-Down` action `Open selected drop-down list` (though the getting the original IBM CUA documents is extremely hard). Some lists also say `F4` should have the same behaviour but that doesn't work.

Comment: @dummzeuch: In D7, the IDE implements its ellipse buttons as standalone buttons that can simply be tabbed to and then clicked on using the `Space` or `Enter` key. `Alt-Down` does open its drop-down lists, though.  Delphi switched to the new Galileo IDE in D8, which introduced the new UI that (amongst other things) embeds the ellipse buttons in the input fields.